# SQL - check if a value is in column list

Tags: sql

what is the SQL WHERE clause which checks if a column TopicID('1,5,14,18') has the value '1'?

```
SELECT  TOP 10 *
FROM    topics
WHERE   {TopicID has the value '1'}
```

thanks.

Comment: What is the datatype of the TopicId field?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I just interpret your question incorrectly. I think you need `like`:

```
SELECT  TOP 10 *
FROM    topics
WHERE   TopicID like '1,%' or TopicID like '%,1' or TopicID like '%,1,%' or TopicID = '1'
```

Comment: It is hard to tell from the question but I think you are correct this is more likely what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If TopicId is a numeric field then:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM topics where TopicId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you use a [=](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-equal) for numerals columns and the [like](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) for matching patterns in columns. So in your case you will have to use the `like` as you are checking for a certain pattern.